# Symfony Route breaks Debug Toolbar

Tags: php, symfony

After loading my Twig-Template by Controller and showing it - it takes a while and i get this error displayed: "An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found)."

Now i researched about 2 hours and can't find the right solution for me! I found the "thing" causing this issue - its the following route:

```
showPage:
pattern: /{a}/{b}/{c}
defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Page:show, a: null, b: null, c: / }
requirements:
    b: \d+
    c: .+
```

I changed the order in routing_dev.yml so that routing.yml will be imported before WDT so it can override it - routing_dev.yml looks now like:

```
_main:
    resource: routing.yml

_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator
```

I use the current Symfony-Version 2.5.0 - the .htaccess file is the default one from Symfony2-Repo - mod_rewrite and mod_alias are enabled!

If i go to a non-existing page and symfony says no route for "bla" found - the toolbar works.

Do you have an Idea how to make an exception for WDT-Routes?

Comment: did you tried to run `app/console router:debug` & `app/console router:match` commands , these might give you a clue

Comment: did you try importing you `_main` resource **after** symfony profiler route?

Comment: @tawfekov thx - found that route is working

Comment: @Igor after i find the error it works in this way too (i reseted it because its the default order by setting up the project from symfony repo).

Is there a possibility to enable some kind of error-Reporting to EventListener - to see if an Error occurds there? (In my Case i wanted to pass an QueryBuilder-Object to $dbalConnection->fetchAll() which is not possible because the method self requires Query to be string.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong with my thought it were a route Problem - the Problem caused in an EventListener which used Doctrine DBAL QueryBuilder and tried to pass the Object to "fetchAll" of DBAL-Connection.

This cause in an Error but Symfony doesn't tell anywhere it only shows my Site and says 404 for Debug-Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Open log file `app/logs/dev.log` and search for `CRITICAL` keyword, You will found the `Fatal Error` that not catched by Symfony. Try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but I had the same situation and it was really hard to find the answer. It's exactly what nPoday said here on Jun 9 2014: I had a listener that was throwing an error, though it wasn't Doctrine related. It was an issue with an AWS wrapper, which wasn't even being fired by the application on startup nor the page I was loading that exhibited the issue. Definitely check your listeners, disable them one by one, and you might find the debug toolbar suddenly starts working.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that may break the toolbar, one of the most common ones is an unfronted error. So make sure you check all your logs before you pull all your hair out.

In my case there was `"NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Access level to UserBundle\Entity\User::$id must be protected (as in class FOS\UserBundle\Model\User) or weaker in ..."` since my `id` was private.

After fixing that toolbar has reappeard.